# Assign an html id to a sass variable as value

Tags: html, css, sass

I am pretty new to web development, so if you don't understand the explanation of my question, pls let me know.
In my html File I have multiple divs with the same classname which are also defined by an unique id.

```
<div class="example" id="130" >
<div class="example" id="240" >
<div class="example" id="15" >
<div class="example" id="870" >
<div class="example" id="640" >
```

Now I want to hand the id over to my sass file, and assign the id as a value to a variable. So at the end I want have the id name as my timer length. Like so:

```
$timer_length: 130
```

This way I want to manage the timer length of multiple individual timers.
I don't know if this is even possible. Maybe there is a simple way to do this.

Comment: The SASS to CSS compiler can't read anything from the HTML, it runs on build time, before any specific HTML is loaded. CSS itself can refer to ID values in selectors but not translate them to values (unless you have a closed list of possible values then SASS might help). Essentially, you need JavaScript for runtime processing.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this not sure about this will help you or not.

If you know how many individuals are then you can give them a dynamic name something like `example_1` where `example_` and `1` is static with that you can fetch a specific individual's `id` then you can use with the help of JavaScript as @Noam said in the comments.

```js
var dynamic_number = 2;
var elm_name = "example_" +dynamic_number;
console.log(elm_name);
var elements = document.getElementsByName( elm_name );
var value = elements[0].getAttribute( 'id' );
alert("Time for individule " + dynamic_number +" is: "+ value);
```

```html
<div class="example" name="example_1" id="130" >
<div class="example" name="example_2" id="240" >
<div class="example" name="example_3" id="15" >
<div class="example" name="example_4" id="870" >
<div class="example" name="example_5" id="640" >
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an `attr` property that you can use in css, but according to [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=attr), it's currently only supported for the `content` attribute.
You may need to use JavaScript to do what you want.

Since you seems to use your IDs as a data, I suggest you to use `data-[...]`.
Here is an example with your IDs as `data-length` to set up div length :

```js
let examples = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
for (let i = 0; i < examples.length; i++) {
  examples[i].style.width = examples[i].dataset.length+"px";
}
```

```css
.example{
  height:10px;
  background-color:orange;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example" data-length="130"></div>
<div class="example" data-length="240"></div>
<div class="example" data-length="15" ></div>
<div class="example" data-length="870"></div>
<div class="example" data-length="640"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

@TheHunter Shergrill
suddenly I don't know how many individuals there are.  The id name should not be controlled by me or set static in the future. Basically, I am searching for a way to let the user set the length of a timer. The length will manipulate the design and colouring of the whole div. The whole design thing works. But I am having a hard time figuring out how to import the set value into my sass file. I don't know if the id solution is the best one or if there are any other ways to do this.

Comment: @Fabio If you want to add more details to your problem please edit your question instead so everyone will see it. If you want user interaction, you'll need to use JS and get the value by doing something similar as TheHunter's answer or mine. If you have only few option, you can make specific css classes to set your timer, but you still need js to apply the correct class on user interaction.